# Carriage return without line break on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, line-breaks, carriage-return

So I have this simple statusbar implementation:

```
def status_update(current, top, label="Progress"):
    workdone = current/top
    print("\r{0:s}: [{1:30s}] {2:.1f}%".format(label,'#' * int(workdone * 30), workdone*100), end="", flush=True)
    if workdone == 1:
        print()
```

Works as expected on linux.

On Windows (10, in my case), however, `\r` apparently creates a new line for each output instead of overwriting the preceding.

How do I stop that? (Preferably in a way that does not break linux compatibility.)

Comment: The classic Windows console automatically advances the cursor to the next line when the last column is written. In Windows 10 this can be disabled by using virtual terminal mode.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be best way to do this, but works. Just use \b.

```
def status_update(current, top, label="Progress"):
    workdone = current/top
    if not hasattr(status_update, "length"):
        status_update.length = 0
    str1="{0:s}: [{1:30s}] {2:.1f}%".format(label,'#' * int(workdone * 30), workdone*100)
    print(('\b'*status_update.length)+str1, end="", flush=True)
    status_update.length=len(str1)
    if workdone == 1:
        print()
```

here I'm backspacing number of characters printed in last call of status_update